# Convert Number of Days to Years, months and days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table that show the number of days an item has been reserved for:

| ITEMID | Days Reserved |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 254 |
| 101 | 4325 |
| 102 | 1355 |
| etc |  |

I'd like to convert the number of days to years, month, and days using SQL like:

| ITEMID | Days Reserved | Reservation Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 254 | 0 Years, 8 Months, 10 Days |
| 101 | 4325 | 11 Years, 10 Months, 3 Days |
| 102 | 1355 | 3 Years, 8 Months, 16 Days |
| etc |  |  |

I've found lots of ways to do this in Excel and other languages, but no examples on how to do this in Oracle SQL.

Comment: The result would depend on the date it starts from; there will be leap years, and months with different number of days in them. Or do you want just approximate values with assumptions like 365 days per year and 365/12 days in a month? What are the rules?

Comment: That's a good point and something that I had been thinking about. The number of days is a calculation of the sum of the difference of various date ranges the item was reserved for. I don't think it matters about the precision of days. As a matter of fact, the tertiary number could be weeks instead of days.

Comment: I'd be using an interval in postgres, python or go.
Looks like there is interval support in oracle.
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=oracle+date+interval&t=braveed&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
with YrTbl as (
  select 100 as ItemId, 254 as DaysReserved from dual union all
  select 101 as ItemId, 4325 as DaysReserved from dual union all
  select 102 as ItemId, 1355 as DaysReserved from dual 
  ),
FindParts as (
  select ItemID
       , trunc(DaysReserved/365.2425) as Yrs
       , trunc((DaysReserved
            -trunc(DaysReserved/365.2425)*365.2425)/30.44) as Months
       , trunc(DaysReserved
            - trunc(DaysReserved/365.2425)*365.2425
            - trunc((DaysReserved
                -trunc(DaysReserved/365.2425)*365.2425)/30.44)*30.44) as Days
  from YrTbl
  )
select ItemID
     , to_char(Yrs) || ' Years, ' 
       || to_char(Months)|| ' Months, ' 
       || to_char(Days) || ' Days' as ReservationPeriod
from FindParts
```

But, I have a feeling that you have already considered something like this and looking for something 'magical'??

BTW: 365.2425 is average no of days in a year in Gregorian Calendar, and 30.44 is average days in month.

Alternative using ADD_MONTHS and MONTHS_BETWEEN (and assuming that the DaysReserved is counted until the current date):

```sql
with YrTbl as (
  select 100 as ItemId, 254 as DaysReserved from dual union all
  select 101 as ItemId, 4325 as DaysReserved from dual union all
  select 102 as ItemId, 1355 as DaysReserved from dual union all
  select 999 as ItemId, 5 as DaysReserved from dual
  ),
FindParts as (
  select ItemId
       , DaysReserved
       , TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN( CURRENT_DATE
                             , CURRENT_DATE - DaysReserved) / 12 ) as Yrs
       , TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN( CURRENT_DATE
                             , ADD_MONTHS( CURRENT_DATE - DaysReserved
                                         , TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN( CURRENT_DATE
                                                               , CURRENT_DATE- DaysReserved) / 12 ) * 12
           ))) as Months
       , CURRENT_DATE
         - ADD_MONTHS( CURRENT_DATE - DaysReserved
                     , -- Add the years back
                       TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN( CURRENT_DATE
                                           , CURRENT_DATE- DaysReserved) / 12 ) * 12
                       + -- Add the Months back
                       TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN( CURRENT_DATE
                                           , ADD_MONTHS( CURRENT_DATE- DaysReserved
                                                       , TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN( CURRENT_DATE
                                                                             , CURRENT_DATE- DaysReserved) / 12 ) * 12
          )))) as Days
   from YrTbl
)
select ItemID,DaysReserved, Yrs,  Months, Days, to_char(Yrs) || ' Years, ' || to_char(Months)|| ' Months, ' || to_char(Days) || ' Days' 
from FindParts
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports two `INTERVAL` data types:

- `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` and
- `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`.

There are fixed numbers of the smaller precision components in each interval:

- For `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` there is always 12 months in a year; and
- For `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` there is always 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour, 60 seconds in a minute and 1,000,000,000 nanoseconds in a second.

However, there is not a fixed number of days in a year (sometimes 365 and sometimes 366) or a fixed number of days in a month (sometimes 28, 30 or 31) so converting a number of days to years, months and days depends on when you start counting from.

If you just want the years and months then you can start from an epoch date (i.e. `1900-01-01`) and add the number of days and then find the difference from the epoch as an `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH`:

```sql
SELECT itemid,
       ((DATE '1900-01-01' + Days_Reserved) - DATE '1900-01-01') YEAR TO MONTH
         AS year_month_reserved
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ITEMID, Days_Reserved) AS
SELECT 100,  254 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 4325 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 1355 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEMID | YEAR_MONTH_RESERVED |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | +00-08 |
| 101 | +11-10 |
| 102 | +03-09 |

*(Which rounds the months to the nearest full month.)*

If you want days as well then:

```sql
SELECT itemid,
       days_reserved,
       TRUNC(months_reserved/12) || ' years '
       || MOD(months_reserved, 12) || ' months '
       || ( (DATE '1900-01-01' + Days_Reserved)
            - ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1900-01-01', months_reserved)
          ) || ' days'
         AS reservation_period
FROM   (
  SELECT itemid,
         days_reserved,
         TRUNC(
           MONTHS_BETWEEN(
             DATE '1900-01-01' + Days_Reserved,
             DATE '1900-01-01'
           )
         ) AS months_reserved
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for starting at the epoch of 1900-01-01, outputs:

| ITEMID | DAYS_RESERVED | RESERVATION_PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 254 | 0 years 8 months 11 days |
| 101 | 4325 | 11 years 10 months 4 days |
| 102 | 1355 | 3 years 8 months 17 days |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mxodKfmU)

Answer (score 0):

Preparation of test data

```
with
  t0 as (
    select 254 days_reserved from dual union all
    select 4325 from dual union all
    select 1355 from dual union all
    select 37 from dual union all
    select 19 from dual union all
    select 7 from dual
  ),
  t1 as (
    select sysdate as start_date from dual
    -- union all select date '0001-01-01' from dual
    -- union all select date '1900-01-01' from dual
    -- union all select date '2021-04-12' from dual
  ),
```

A CTE that calculates the expiration dates and the intervals in years and months before them.

```
  t2 as (
    select
      t0.*,
      t1.*,
      t1.start_date +
      t0.days_reserved as expiry_date,
      ((t1.start_date + t0.days_reserved) -
       t1.start_date) year to month as y2m
    from t0, t1
  ),
```

A CTE that calculates the correct days for the intervals.

```
  t3 as (
    select
      days_reserved,
      start_date,
      expiry_date,
      y2m -
      numtoyminterval(
        case
          when (start_date + y2m)
             > expiry_date then 1
          else 0
        end, 'month'
      ) as y2m,
      expiry_date -
      ((start_date + y2m) -
       numtoyminterval(
         case
           when (start_date + y2m)
              > expiry_date then 1
           else 0
         end, 'month'
       )) as days
    from t2
  )
```

A query that displays the results.

```
select
  days_reserved,
  start_date,
  expiry_date,
  to_char(extract(year from y2m))||' years, '||
  to_char(extract(month from y2m))||' months, '||
  to_char(days)||' days' as Reservation_Period
from t3;
```

Results:

```
+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| DAYS_RESERVED | START_DATE | EXPIRY_DATE |     RESERVATION_PERIOD      |
+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
|           254 | 2024-01-11 | 2024-09-21  | 0 years, 8 months, 10 days  |
|          4325 | 2024-01-11 | 2035-11-14  | 11 years, 10 months, 3 days |
|          1355 | 2024-01-11 | 2027-09-27  | 3 years, 8 months, 16 days  |
|            37 | 2024-01-11 | 2024-02-17  | 0 years, 1 months, 6 days   |
|            19 | 2024-01-11 | 2024-01-30  | 0 years, 0 months, 19 days  |
|             7 | 2024-01-11 | 2024-01-18  | 0 years, 0 months, 7 days   |
+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JYZf7Z6Y).